# What should the connection string be when using Azure Sql Failover groups?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

Ok so I have set up a Azure Sql Failover group at `mydatabase.databsae.windows.net` which contains 2 servers:

- `mydatabase1.databsae.windows.net`
- `mydatabase2.databsae.windows.net`

I go to [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/) to get my Sql Azure Connection String which looks like so:

`Server=tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net;Database=mySqlDatabase;
User ID=MyUser@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;`

Now the problem lies in **User ID=MyUser@[serverName]** I have tried:

`User ID=MyUser@mydatabase` but that didn't work and repeatedly returns the error:

> Database 'mySqlDatabase' on server 'mydatabase' is not currently
>   available. Please retry the connection later

I also tried `User ID=MyUser@mydatabase1` and that **did** work.

But the problem with the above in the connection string is that when I do failover to `mydatabase2` I will need to go and update all my connection strings.

So what is the correct connection string when using Sql Failover groups?

Comment: Documentation states you should have cname listener `Failover group read-write listener: A DNS CNAME record formed as <failover-group-name>.database.windows.net that points to the current primary server URL. It allows the read-write SQL applications to transparently reconnect to the primary database when the primary changes after failover. `...can you check..I did n't experiment with azure failover groups,but for onpremises you need an listener,so same should be the case there

Comment: demo here :https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37968.working-with-azure-sql-auto-failover-group.aspx

Comment: @TheGameiswar actually that link provides a note explaining my situation, I will post an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a current limitation of failover groups:

> Note: If at this point you go to SSMS and try to connect to your
>   Primary/Secondary database using above listeners, you will receive
>   error and will not be able to login. Ideally it should have allowed,
>   but it currently fails, as it tries to connect to the Master database
>   which is currently not part of the group. This is currently being
>   worked upon and should be resolved soon. Till then, workaround is to
>   provide the database name while connecting to server. Use the option
>   button to provide database name.

what this means is that currently only the following connection strings will work:

```
Server=tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net;Database=mySqlDatabase;
User ID=MyUser@mydatabase1;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

OR

```
Server=tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net;Database=mySqlDatabase;
User ID=MyUser@mydatabase2;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

Unfortunately this renders the automatic failover completely useless as you need to then reconfigure all your connection strings

Ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37968.working-with-azure-sql-auto-failover-group.aspx

Comment: Try adding your connection string with explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Server=tcp:mydatabase.database.windows.net;Database=mySqlDatabase;
User ID=MyUser@mydatabase;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;MultiSubnetFailover=True;
```

Comment: I've already tried that, it returns the error: `Database 'mySqlDatabase' on server 'mydatabase' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later`